# Why does this change in the URL affect JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm teaching myself JQuery by creating a lightbox. My JQuery works when I enter in this URL:

```
http://localhost/bookshook/other_projects/zachitemdescription.php?id=21
```

But when I enter in this URL, it doesn't work:

```
http://localhost/bookshook/other_projects/zachitemdescription.php/?id=21
```

Why does that extra backslash stop the jQuery?

Comment: what is the diff between above two, I can't see?

Comment: @Mritunjay A trailing `/` after `.php`

Comment: its not that it stops the jQuery, its that it now treats the `php` file like a subfolder, and the `?id=21` as just part of the index of that folder. if won't work anywhere in HTML, not just in jQuery.

Comment: what your jquery does?

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't just stop jQuery - it's a request to a completely different page.

The first URL is calling `zachitemdescription.php`, with the querystring values of `id=21`.

The second URL is calling the default document of the `zachitemdescription.php` *folder*, with querystring values of `id=21`, which I'm guessing does not exist in your case.